# How to fix the screen orientation for inappbrowser

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, screen-orientation, landscape-portrait, inappbrowser

I am opening an url in the inappbrowser in my app. My app is fixed to landscape mode and would like the inappbrowser to be fixed to landscape too. My app is fixed using the cordova screenorientation plugin, but the inappbrowser does not get fixed to any orientation I set.

Answer (score 0):

I found the fix, the latest inappbrowser plugin should include the change -

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-5649

Check in change - 
https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git;h=b9f8fcd

Comment: Could you please explain what I have to do? Where can I disable UINavigationController?

Comment: I found this link, which shows the change, unfortunately I haven't tried it, s can't verify it. Hope it works for you - https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cordova-plugin-inappbrowser.git;a=blobdiff;f=src/ios/CDVInAppBrowser.m;h=aed735cf57022c8eeeb3a539ebb485d53cbcc32e;hp=68675c57a8e0608a8cf5bfc2c9a9356e766b2e74;hb=b9f8fcd;hpb=11f833b46d1318eee6b073d6ff2ec380fcb1ab89